# Is there a way to add unique identifier to inserted text in doc in google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-apps-script-addon

I am inserting a text in the active cursor position every time a user click the button however, I want to tag a unique identifier in the the inserted text so that later on when I get all the inserted texts I can differentiate them from each other.

Answer (score 0):

You could try generating UUIDs for each one generated utilizing the uuid npm module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid

Comment: Thanks for suggesting but this is not what i'm looking for.